# JQuery Syntax Errors in .js file, are my Script tags wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cdn, src

```
<script>
    let sectionFlags = {
        objective: true; // '} expected'
        coursework: true;
        education: true;
        technicalSkills:true;
    }
    function toggleSection(id){
        sectionFlags[id] { //'} expected'
        if(sectionFlags[id]){
            $('#' + id.css('display','block'));
        }
        else {
            'none'; //'} expected'
        }
      }
    }
    let resume;
    function displayObjective() {
        $('#objective').html(htmlFrag);
  }
function displayFromJson() {
    displayObjective(); //'} expected'
    $("#objectiveHeading").on('click', {id: 'objective'}, toggleSection) // '} expected'
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('resume.json'), function(resumeData) {
        resume = resumeData;
        displayFromJson();
    });
});
</script>
<script type = "text\javascript" src = 
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src ='resume.html'></script> // 'JSX expressions must have one parent element'
```

I'm having issues with this .js file. I'm supposed to load the jquery using a cdn, which from all of the resources I've read is done in the script tag at the end of the file. After more searching I realized I needed to include the "text\javascript" as the type in the tag, but this did not fix any of my errors. As far as I can tell from my searches I am loading it correctly.

The errors I am getting are '} expected' and 'JSX expressions must have one parent element'. I've commented where these errors are. Any help would be appreciated, as far as I can tell there aren't missing braces... I am not getting anywhere with the researching I am doing. 
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Your `let sectionFlags` is an object, so should have commas rather than semicolons. That is likely messing up the rest of your script.

Comment: Syntax errors all over the place. If this is a `.js` file, there should be no `<script>` tags. Separate your object properties with a comma i.e `objective: true,`. You'll want to define the `jQuery` shorthand `$` or just use `jQuery` instead. i.e `jQuery.getJSON..`. `src ='resume.html'` is just wrong - that should be a `js` file. I recommend going through a tutorial, no shame in that.

Comment: jQuery will also need to be included *before* you try to use properties that it defines.

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful! I'm definitely going to do a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing these semicolons to commas.

```
let sectionFlags = {
    objective: true,
    coursework: true,
    education: true,
    technicalSkills:true
};
```

Comment: This helped, thank you! I had riddled the thing with syntax errors.